# Parse.com + NSDate : Convert Parse Date Retrieved to local timezone

Tags: ios, date, parse-platform, nsdate

I'm having a very hard problem downloading objects from parse for "TODAY".

The objects I'm downloading are events. Each has a startTime property (NSDate) - which stores the date and the time of the event. From reading Parse documentation and other questions on stackoverflow.com, the dates in Parse are stored as "UTC" time zone.

When I do not get any results if I try to something like:

```
[query whereKey:@"startTime" greaterThan:[NSDate date]];
```

Right now I do not care about the time start time, just care about the date in the following format: "MM/dd"

I have tried to retrieve all the objects and convert the start times to local times but have not had any success. When I do the conversion, the startTimes are actually a day off (a day behind). So if the event is the 08/29 - it prints 08/28.

I tried to convert it to local time and then compare if the result is equal to today's date but still no luck.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/"];
[dateFormat Time:@"MM/dd/":[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDateFormatter *todayDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[todayDateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
NSString *todayString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
NSString *activityDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:event.startTime];

if ([todayString isEqualToString:activity.activityDate]){
  //add to events array. 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate it. I've spent so many hours trying to get this work and have not been successful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse uses UTC time. So to convert it to your time it should be:

```
NSDate *objDate = [parseObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSString *date = [format stringFromDate:objDate];
```